# MVVM light support in VS 2015

Tags: mvvm-light

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to get full code snippet support for MVVM light in VS 2015 RTM?

I'm trying to install it into the gallery via the instructions at http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/

That works fine for VS 2013 but there's no matches when I search for "mvvm light" in online "Extensions and Updates" in VS 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7693) suggests that though it's not officially supported yet, there is a vsix installer that can be downloaded from there that worked for me on VS 2015 RTM.

The project templates from that vsix only support up to 4.5.1 but I assume the official ones will take advantage of any relevant 4.5.2 features.